# YaST2: Command-line equivalents to GUI naviagtion

Tags: opensuse, yast

I'd like to automate some interactions with yast2. I assume I can do everything on the command line that I can do in the curses interface, but I'm not sure how to figure out what the commands are.

For example, if I want yast2 to use a local ISO as a package repository, I know how to do it through the curses GUI (Software->Add-On Productions, Add, Local ISO Image, Browse, ...).

Is there a way to identify these interactions with arguments that can be passed to yast2 on the command-line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you can't do as much with command line than with the ncurses interface, as yast modules have to individually implement support for CLI.

According to openSUSE 11.1 Reference Guide:

> To use YaST functionality in scripts,
>   YaST provides command line support for
>   individual modules. Not all modules
>   have a command line support. To
>   display the available options of a
>   module, enter:
>
> `yast <module_name> help`
>
> If a module does not provide command
>   line support, the module is started in
>   text mode and the following message
>   appears:
>
> `This YaST module does not support the command line interface.`

(use `yast --list` to list modules)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a command line approach to system configuration, or package management?

If you're looking for package management, openSUSE's command line interface is primarily zypper, not yast.